# velocity.js progress callback function not working

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

I have used velocity.js to animate something on page but in progress callback function does not working for me. I am getting null value for the tweenValue para.

Here is the code.

```js
$element.velocity({
    opacity: 0,
    tween: 1000 // Optional
}, {
    progress: function(elements, complete, remaining, start, tweenValue) {
        console.log((complete * 100) + "%");
        console.log(remaining + "ms remaining!");
        console.log("The current tween value is " + tweenValue)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example works fine when I try it on the document body,

```
$("body").velocity({
    opacity: 0,
    tween: 1000 // Optional
}, {
    progress: function p(elements, complete, remaining, start, tweenValue) {
        console.log((complete * 100) + "%");
        console.log(remaining + "ms remaining!");
        console.log("The current tween value is " + tweenValue)
    }
});
```

It logs messages like the following

```
4%
VM740:8 384ms remaining!
VM740:9 The current tween value is 3.942649342761062
```

I used the latest 1.2.2 version from github,
https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/blob/master/velocity.js
and I used requirejs to load velocity and jquery in the page